# Did we finally clear the queues?

Tags: bug, review-queues

Currently the review queues look like this:

[image]

I can understand that *Help and Improvement* is cleared, but I doubt there are no new answers to old questions...

Out of the queues showing 0 items only the suggested edits is still active, ***but*** only showing me tag wikis for some reason. The others are literally cleared.

Is this a bug due to [the new onboarding system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363485/new-onboarding-for-review-queues)?

Comment: Huh. I'd noticed that the low quality posts queue had very few items in it today - for there to only have been 657 reviews all day (on a weekday) doesn't seem right. I've raised about 50-60 NAA flags that would've gone into the queue: and they've all been dealt with pretty quickly (within about an hour) so something is definitely different.

Comment: well, seems so - especially funny to see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg0P6.png) after about 900 reviews in the queue :) No way suggested edits queue is at 0 really. We've been at near max capacity for the last month. Same bug in [stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubGqb.png) (despite there clearly being reviews to handle)

Comment: oh, and it seems like something is off with sorting - I had a month and a half old suggested tag wiki approved and am reviewing the fourth wiki in a row... Will take further look and report

Comment: Suggested Edits is showing me regular suggested edits. I just assumed I was review suspended on the queues that had 0 posts. Maybe waiting 6-8 months will get me out of the suspension ;-)

Comment: I noticed this from yesterday that LQP and LA were 'batchy' - there was nothing for ages, then suddenly 100 arrived. Today was similar but then the batches stopped coming. I assume the floodgates will open once the powers that be fix whatever produces the batches.

Comment: Probably not worth a new Meta question as it's been discussed several times before, but again this highlights that in the review popup box, several of the queues are shown as red, even though the queues are empty.

Comment: This definitely seems to be a bug.  I flagged three late answers as NAA but they're not showing up as per https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52032462#52032462 despite still being pending.

Comment: I have about 20 NAA flags pending at the moment and the only reviews I see are from ♦BR. I can't see anyone reviewing my flags. Please fix it as soon as possible

Comment: Hey I was involved in clearing the suggested edits this morning :)

Comment: Over two hours later, still only 657 LQP reviews for the day. Very odd.

Comment: The numbers seem to be fixed - suggested edits is back at the usual ~470 to go through